# How to find all references for URL

Tags: citations, productivity

I want to find all the papers that have cited a specific URL (which is in my case http://sable.github.io/soot/, https://github.com/soot-oss/soot, etc).

I tried searching those in Google scholar, Microsoft academic, etc but failed to find useful information.

How can I do that?